# Protect from multi requests - WebAPI

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-web-api

I have next problem
I have user. User has column in database - Tickets. - Ticket is internal currency.
Now when User click on website BUY - I go to webapi===> BL (Class library)

I take user from DB - check if he has tickets and if Yes -- i do my logic (and i go to DAL - and put this counter down).

Problem is - If i click on website on button BUY -- so fast -- I can buy twice.

**Example**

User has 1 ticket

He want to buy something -- price 1 ticket

User click fast 2 times on button BUY

**1 request**
Go to WebApi ==> go to BL ==> Bl take from DAL User from DB and check if he has Ticket --- YES HE HAS ===> do logic and put Ticket counter to 0

**2 request**
Go to WebApi ==> go to BL ==> Bl take from DAL User from DB and check if he has Ticket --- YES HE HAS **here is the problem** ===> do logic and put Ticket counter to 0

So I dont know how protect from this bug....or how is the better re-make database structure for this?

Comment: Are you using straight ado.net or using Entity Framework (or something else) for an ORM? The reason I ask is that Sql Server has the option to use a versioning row and EF can take advantage of this to provide a concurrency check for you. If you use ado.net you can still take advantage but you have to manually implement this.

Comment: Im using EF 6.0

Comment: If you cannot handle multiple button events you could disable the button after the first click.

Comment: Then you could implement that: See [Handling Concurrency with the Entity Framework 6](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/handling-concurrency-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application). You want to store the user's version value and pass that along to any call you make to the web api. You should then send the updated value back as a response so it can be reused. EF will execute a check for you and throw an exception if you try to update the same value multiple times.

Answer (score 3):

You need to change your update logic in such a way that of several concurrent updates only one would succeed.

For example, if your DB table has `TicketId` and `TicketCount` fields, you see that you've got `n` tickets remaining, and you would like to decrement the number of tickets, rather than doing this

```
UPDATE Ticket
SET TicketCount=@NewTicketCount
WHERE TicketId=@TicketId
```

do this:

```
UPDATE Ticket
SET TicketCount=@NewTicketCount
WHERE TicketId=@TicketId AND TicketCount=@OldTicketCount
```

When you run the second update concurrently from multiple threads, only one will succeed, updating a single row. All other threads would see this request updating zero rows. They should take it as an indication of failure, and return the corresponding status code to the caller of Web API.

> I'm using EF 6.0

Then you can rely on [EF 6 implementation of optimistic concurrency](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/handling-concurrency-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application), which does a similar thing automatically for you.

Comment: Since OP uses Entity Framework, it worth noting that it supports optimistic concurrency out of the box and (with some configuration) can produce such update queries and generate exception on concurrency conflict (0 rows updated).

Comment: @Evk Thank you, I didn't see that comment.

Answer (score 0):

Create a temporary variable to hold the BUYING status while its being processing.
This variable can contains some user ID to be personated.

SOmething like:

```
      ' At the click...

      If UserBuyingNow is nothing
         UserIsBuying = User_ID
         ...
         (proceed to your logic)
         ...
         (at the end, clear the status variable)
         UserIsBuying = null
      else
         (user is already buying)
         exit
      End If
```

You may also work over SQL using a StoredProcedure to set a temporary field with TRUE while buying and, at the end of process, call another StoredProcedure to clear that field.

Anyway, the logic is the same as above, but at database level.